# JMeter issue with javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message when testing GCP CloudRun

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jmeter, google-cloud-run

I am using JMeter to run some POST requests to CloudRun for my API. When I run the process, the POST returns the error:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|12|Single Insert 1-1|2022-04-22 17:39:28.479 BST|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "unexpected_message"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|12|Single Insert 1-1|2022-04-22 17:39:28.479 BST|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Received fatal alert: unexpected_message (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
...etc...
```

I have created a certificate with:

`keytool -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA`

then copied the file `clientkeystore` under the `bin` folder and added in the `system.properties` file:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=clientkeystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypassword
```

but nothing changes when it run versus a GCP/CloudRun instance. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your application requires a [client-side certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate) you need to **get the appropriate one** and not to generate a new random one so if this is the case you will need to [import the relevant certificate into keystore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/rstep1.html)

```
keytool -import -alias your-certificate-alias -file /path/to/your/certificate.cer -keystore clientkeystore.p12-storepass mypassword
```

and change the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` to include the file extension:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=clientkeystore.p12
```

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

If your application can be accessed by anyone without having to provide the client-side certificate just remove the properties as you don't need them.